# How do I separate a line in TiKz with arrows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows

Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% a straight line segment
\draw[->-=0.5] (1,0) -- (0,0);
\draw[->-=0.5] (0,0) -- (-1,0);
% the ticks and their labels
\foreach \x [count=\i start from 0] in {-1,...,1}
  \draw[xshift=\x cm] node[below,fill=white] (\i) {\x};

\draw[->] (-1,0.15) to [out=65, in=115] (0,0.15);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But I would like to separate the number line like this instead of being connected:

[image]

Comment: Your code gives a different output than the image you uploaded. Which one do you want? The one we see here?

Comment: @Alenanno Yes, my code output is not working the way I want. I would like my code output to look like the picture I posted, but I cannot get the lines to separate, and also have the arrows appear on the ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
1 \arrow[r] & 0 \arrow[r] & -1 \arrow[l,bend left]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unless I misunderstood your request, you don't need decorations with this type of graph. Using your `foreach` you can draw an arrow for each node. I had to use an `if` statement though to avoid typesetting an extra arrow on the right.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}

\tikzset{
    every node/.style={
        minimum width=2cm
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->]

\foreach \name [count=\xi from -1] in {1,...,-1}{
    \coordinate (\name) at (\name,0);
    \node[yshift=.3pt,] (n\name) at (\name,0) {$\xi$};

    \ifnum\name=1\relax
    \else
        \draw[shorten >=2.5mm,shorten <=2.5mm] (\name,0) -- (\name+1,0);
    \fi
}
\draw (1,-.15) to [out=225, in=315] (0.1,-.15);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There should be `{$\xi$}`, so math mode is used.

Comment: @egreg Fixed! :)